# Sentence meaning depending on position of “nicht”

Tags: meaning, negation

What is the difference in meaning between these sentences?

> Ich spreche die Deutsche nicht.
>   Ich spreche nicht die Deutsche.

Also:

> Ich bin nicht der Lehrer.
>   Ich bin der Lehrer nicht.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the first two sentences are somehow wrong: it's either *die deutsche Sprache* or *das Deutsch* (but not *die Deutsche*, which means *German woman*). I would say (paradoxically)

> *Ich spreche kein Deutsch* or *Ich kann kein Deutsch.*

For the second variant, with *nicht*, it sounds like something is missing.

> *Ich spreche nicht Deutsch, sondern Rumänisch.*

As for the second sentence, first you *must* capitalize *"lehrer"*. The first of the options sounds to my ears like something like in this example:

> Ich bin nicht der Lehrer, sondern ein sehr alter Student.

while the second option sounds strange. Then

> Ich bin kein Lehrer

is the right option.

Comment: Regarding "die deutsche" meaning "die deutsche Sprache", this is possible given the right context: "Welche Sprachen er wohl sprechen kann?" - "Die deutsche jedenfalls schonmal nicht."

Comment: Well, then of course “die deutsche” can also mean “the german blood orange”.

Comment: Rather than "meaning", perhaps we should call this "referring (to)". What I meant to say was that this context is vital, without (special) context, it cannot refer to the German language: "Die deutsche ist schön." (Was?)

Comment: @c.p. "I would say (paradoxically) _Ich spreche kein Deutsch_" Why paradoxically? It's the content of the shortest German phrase book :-)

Comment: @divby0 because of *kein* :).

Comment: @c.p. I got that :-) But think of Monty Python's "Dirty Hungarian Phrasebook" skit to see why there's not necessarily a paradox.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes still the negation can also be put at the end of a sentence, as was done in the episode "Suppen-Kaspar" of [Struwwelpeter](http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Der_Struwwelpeter):

> Ich esse keine Suppe! Nein!
>   Ich esse meine Suppe nicht!
>   Nein, meine Suppe ess’ ich nicht!

Answer (score 2):

## Common Case

> Ich bin nicht der Lehrer...

Emphasis either on *nicht*

> ... darum geht mich das nichts an.

or on *Lehrer*

> ... sondern der Schuldirektor.

## First Word

> Nicht ich bin der Lehrer...

emphsis on *ich*

> ... sondern Herr Patzke.

## Wrong

> Ich bin der Lehrer nicht.