# Position of "nicht" in a sentence containing a "vollverb" and "modalverb"

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, negation

Is it

> Ich kann nicht es dir sagen.

oder

> Ich kann es dir nicht sagen.

Sometimes I see "nicht" after "modalverb" directly and sometimes before "vollverb". Is there any difference and are they interchangeable?
And in this sentence

> Ich habe es dir sagen gemocht.

where must we put "nicht" to negate it?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/sentence-meaning-depending-on-position-of-nicht

Answer (score 5):

In the following, I always assume, you want to negate a whole main clause (or its Vollverb, respectively).

You can find the position of the *nicht* by formulating the same sentence with a single verb, then replacing the verb with the modal verb and putting Vollverb at the very end. Or with other words: *Nicht* has the same position as it would have, if there were a single verb in the sentence, but is always before the Vollverb. Some examples:

> Ich sage es dir nicht. → Ich kann es dir nicht sagen.
>   Er ist nicht zu Hause. → Er möchte nicht zu Hause sein.
>   Du gibst mir das Geschenk nicht. → Du sollst mir das Geschenk nicht geben.
>   Ich bin nicht glücklich. → Ich bin nicht glücklich gewesen.
>   Ich stelle mir das nicht vor. → Ich kann mir das nicht vorstellen.

Basically, [these rules](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Negation/Stellung/nichtkontrast.html?MenuId=Sentence730) hold.

There is a slight exception in case of prepositional objects and free prepositional adverbials: The tendency shifts to positioning the *nicht* after these elements in case of a modal verb (* marks the more common variant):

> Ich warte nicht auf sie. → Ich kann nicht auf sie warten. / Ich kann auf sie nicht warten.
>   Sie streitet sich nicht mit ihm.* / Sie streitet sich mit ihm nicht. → Sie hat sich nicht mit ihm gestritten. / Sie hat sich mit ihm nicht gestritten.*
>   Er schläft nicht wegen des Lärms. / Er schläft wegen des Lärms nicht. → Er kann wegen des Lärms nicht schlafen.

---

Finally, to your example sentence with a double modal verb:

> Ich sage es dir nicht. → Ich mag es dir nicht sagen. → Ich habe es dir nicht sagen mögen.

Here, *mögen* is not turned into a past participle because of the double modal verb. Note, however, that in such situations the imperfect is preferred to avoid the double infinitive:

> Ich sage es dir nicht. → Ich mochte es dir nicht sagen.

Answer (score 2):

The position of "nicht" (in the second example) is correct. However, the third example sentence is grammatically incorrect. It should read:

> Ich habe es dir nicht sagen mögen.

Comment: How can you tell which position is correct?